# Populating ExternalLink from Model in Wicket

Tags: model, wicket

I am sure I am overlooking something very basic here, but I just don't get how to create an ExternalLink inside a WebMarkupContainer from the model of the WebMarkupContainer.

```
    container = new WebMarkupContainer("view");
    container.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    container.setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<Article>(new Article()));
    container.add(new Label("title"));
    container.add(new MultiLineLabel("article"));       
    container.add(new ExternalLink("originalUrl",???)));
```

I'd appreciate hints how to create this url. I am sure there must be a way to obtain a reference to the model of the container, I just don't get it :( Why doesn't it just work the same way as Label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't check it right now but if you're using a CompoundPropertyModel on your container, `container.add(new ExternalLink("originalUrl")));` should work. If not, try using `container.add(new ExternalLink("originalUrl", model.bind("originalUrl")));`.

Comment: the first constructor does not exist, that was my first guess. just like label or mulitlinelabel. the second doesn't fit either on first glance but if I don't create the model "inline" but like this: final IModel<String> urlModel = model.bind("originalUrl"); it works. thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Yashima The missing constructor is very strange, maybe I'd even call it a bug but right now I don't have the time to check jira if there's an open issue related to this...

Comment: I was a bit surprised as well, that this didn't work quite as intuitiv as I expected. I am not practiced much yet with Wicket therefore I assumed I was going about it completely wrong. Thanks for your help!